# Is there a way I can have half my hard drive partitioned to NTFS?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs

I am currently running Ubuntu off of one hard drive (I currently only have one in my computer at the moment) tried to install windows via a boot disk. I get to the setup and it asks where to install Windows, but I can't click on any of the hard drives because they are not in NTFS format.

I was wondering if I can format HALF of my hard drive to NTFS so I can install windows on here aswell (Dual Boot). Please help me. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) (see also [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions))

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's easiest for dual booting to install Windows first - this is because once you install Windows it'll over write the GRUB bootloader and not give you the option to boot into Linux.

It's just a recommendation though - you can easily repair GRUB using Rescatux boot disk, or just boot of Ubuntu Live USB and install\run boot-repair package.

Now for the half NTFS, in Ubuntu firstly install gparted:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open up GParted, resize your partition by shrinking the available space to how big you want the NTFS partition to be.

You will be left with your Ext4 Ubuntu partition, and then a grey 'unallocated space'

Click on that unallocated space and make a new partition with it, select all the space free and select the option to format as NTFS.

When you go to install Windows, you can click the NTFS partition and choose to install there.

[WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

[How to Partition Your Hard Drive for Ubuntu and Windows](http://www.techerator.com/2011/02/how-to-partition-your-hard-drive-for-ubuntu-and-windows/)

Edit: As mentioned once you successfully install Windows you will lose access to Ubuntu on the other patition when booting, and as mentioned do a search for Rescatux or Boot-Repair for Ubuntu to restore GRUB

Answer (score 0):

I think its easy, just install Windows (Ver.) once the installation (.of windows) asks you what do you want to do (upgade or fresh install) do a fresh install (.format) and format the entire hdd (.hard drive) without creating a 3rd partition (1st.Windows Reserved~100MB,2nd Your Windows OS and 3rd Ubuntu) you dont have to.
Once the installation finishe's install ubuntu by pressing a key while you see a keyboard on ubuntu launch at the bottom of your screen, select your languange and then select install ubuntu after that it will ask you at some point how ubuntu will install (along side with windows) yeah you have to select it and then do a normal installation.
Thank you for reading this i hope i helped
~sorry for my bad english i'm from greece~ ^_^